# gcc error- "error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line"

Tags: linux, gcc, ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile tutorial  01 from [enter link description here](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.c)http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html
copy pasted the code from here: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.c
tried to compile (on linux) like the tutorial said with:

```
gcc -o tutorial01 tutorial01.c -lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lz
```

and got an error

```
: /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIT5t82.o: undefined reference to symbol 'av_malloc@@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libavutil.so.51: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to link avutil library, Please add -lavutil while compiling code.

```
gcc -o tutorial01 tutorial01.c -lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lz -lavutil
```

Comment: added , and now have :   /tmp/ccIskNE0.o: In function `main':
tutorial1.c:(.text+0x501): undefined reference to `avcodec_free_frame'
tutorial1.c:(.text+0x50d): undefined reference to `avcodec_free_frame'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status